# Scroll down Event

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, events

I want to add some functionality on an html element, when I scroll down on that element.

```
var El = document.getElementbyId("info");
El.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
    El.style.background="red";
})
```

I want to use that event on an element, not on document or window object.

Answer (score 0):

1. your selector 'getElementbyId' is wrong, the 'b' needs to be a capital
2. Ive added some content so have a viable demo case

```js
document.getElementById('info').addEventListener(
    'scroll',
    function()
    {
        document.getElementById('info').style.background="red";
    },
    false
)
```

```css
    #info{
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    background-color:yellow;
    overflow:scroll;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="info">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>
```

Comment: it does, see the selector